# Can't import react component with gulp and ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a react component which is created locally and when I import the component it gives me this error :

> uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of ..

> warning.j Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of

I tried creating a demo inside the component and the import works fine.  I am not sure if this error is related this issue or import issue.

Comment: Which bundler are you using? What command are you running?

Comment: browserify with babel

Comment: Could you possibly be confusing default and named exports / imports? We can't really help you if you don't post your code (which you should know given the rep you have).

Comment: Are you sure you are importing / exporting the component correctly ? Please share your code for the same.

Also check the guidelines on how to answer questions properly. Include the relevant code portions so that community can help you faster.

Comment: The error you have mentioned is thrown if you pass  wrong element to ReactDOM.render(<Element />,  document.getElementById('root')); Make sure Class Element extends React.Component exists in your code